# Join the two databases in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R so sorry if it's a simple question, how do I join the two databases, with the information of `df1` as the first line and `df2` as the second line.

```
df1<-structure(list(Lat = -23.7, Long = -49.7, 
    AB = 1), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")

> df1
        Lat      Long AB
1     -23.7     -49.7  1

df2<-structure(list(Lat = -23.8, Long = -49.6, 
    AB = 1), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")

> df2
     Lat  Long AB
1  -23.8 -49.6  1
```

Comment: For future reference: (1) `df1` and `df2` are **data frames**, not databases. (2) What you're doing here is **concatenating**, not joining which has a different meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you can use

```
rbind(df1, df2)
```